# Submenu in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, submenu

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The ".submenu" appears only for 1 sec. Can anyone help?

```js
var subopen = document.querySelector(".subopen"),
 submenu = document.querySelector(".sub-menu");

subopen.addEventListener("click", function() {
 if(submenu.classList.contains("hidden") === true) {
  submenu.classList.remove("hidden");
   submenu.classList.add("visible");
 } else {
  submenu.classList.add("hidden");
 };
}, false);
```

```css
.container {
 width: 1200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
nav {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}
.top-nav > ul > li {
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 list-style: none;
}
.top-nav > ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.top-nav > ul li {
 list-style: none;
}

.sub-menu {
 padding: 10px 0px;
 background-color: red;
 width: 100px;
 position: absolute;
}
.hidden {
 display: none;
}
.visible {
 display: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="top-nav">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
    <li>
     <a class="subopen" href="">Galery</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu hidden">
      <li><a href="">Galery1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Galery2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Galery3</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>
```

Comment: First of all 'display: visible' is not valid css (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp). Could you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `href` attribute. Clicking on it is navigating away.

Side note: `classList.contains` returns a boolean, so

```
if(submenu.classList.contains("hidden") === true)
```

could be just

```
if(submenu.classList.contains("hidden"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you have left empty `href` attributes so either **add `#` to `href`** or Remove them.

**Snippet:**

```js
var subopen = document.querySelector(".subopen"),
 submenu = document.querySelector(".sub-menu");

subopen.addEventListener("click", function() {
 if(submenu.classList.contains("hidden") === true) {
  submenu.classList.remove("hidden");
   submenu.classList.add("visible");
 } else {
  submenu.classList.add("hidden");
 };
}, false);
```

```css
.container {
 width: 1200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
nav {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}
.top-nav > ul > li {
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 list-style: none;
}
.top-nav > ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.top-nav > ul li {
 list-style: none;
}

.sub-menu {
 padding: 10px 0px;
 background-color: red;
 width: 100px;
 position: absolute;
}
.hidden {
 display: none;
}
.visible {
 display: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="top-nav">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
    <li>
     <a class="subopen" href="#">Galery</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu hidden">
      <li><a href="">Galery1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Galery2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Galery3</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>
```

> **Note:** I have just added to your link with `subopen`, if you have more alike do as i mentioned to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/hgrzfmnh/)

Your `href` attribute is empty which is causing a redirect. Thus either remove the `href` attribute or add `#` as the value for `href`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="top-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li>
                <a class="subopen" href="#">Galery</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu hidden">
                    <li><a href="#">Galery1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Galery2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Galery3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```